# Duplicate story-id questions: series vs. publication

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, story-identification

What if [one story-ID question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42620/hillbilly-type-family-with-supernatural-powers) asks about a **series** of stories, while [another story-ID question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145873/40s-50s-short-story-about-a-mutant-family-with-psi-powers) asks about a **particular story** which happens to belong to that series. Are they duplicates? If they are duplicates, which one should be closed, or does it depend on which was posted first, or on which is the better question or has the better answer?

(I have no definite opinion on the matter. I don't even see the point of closing story-identification questions at all, seeing as they will not be deleted and will remain on the site forever.)

Comment: Basically the same question: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10051/51379

Comment: @Adamant's question linked above covers the "Are they duplicates?" part, while [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4749/31394) oft-cited question covers the "which one should be closed" part. Ah, the irony of asking a duplicate question about duplicates :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: :-P So, do we mark this one as a duplicate?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm waiting for someone else to cast the first VTC, so that we can get *both* the questions mentioned above linked as duplicates.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: I wasn't certain which way to answer things since the answer to this was basically "these *two* questions answer it".

Comment: @Randal'Thor [The question you linked to](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate) does *not* address my question: in deciding which one to close, is the fact that one is asking about a *series*, while the other is asking about an individual *work* in that series, more important than which came first or which has better answers>